# I want to get value from one method in one class to another class

Tags: java, class, methods, get

I want to  get value from one method in one class to another class. i.e get vale of myinput from method run in connection.class to another variable in another class called search.class

connection.class

```
 public final void run(){
    ......................................................
   ....................................

     String myinput=inputLine.substring(5);
                movedata(myinput);
                    System.out.println("Database selected: "+myinput);}
            handleCommand(inputLine);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        SessionContext.unset();
    }
    owConnection.close();
}


public String movedata(String myinput){
    return myinput;
}
```

I wish to get the value of myinput into another class called search.class

Answer (score 0):

`Connection` class can have a `Search` member, which `myinput` will be set to it when data is available:

```
public String movedata(String myinput){
    this.search.setInput(myinput);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try like 
In your search class , create an **object**

EX:

```
   Connection objConn= new Connetion;
   String myInputCopy=objConn.movedata();
```

You can use this in your search class.
Hope it helps!

Comment: myinput is a local variable i cannot use it

Comment: @user3111030 You have mis-uunderstood java concepts . You cant the value of local variable outside the method. Else you can change the return type , so that you return the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your method movedata just returns what you give it as an argument. If you want to return the local variable you have to use `this`:

```
public String movedata(String myinput){
    return this.myinput;
}
```

But then again, why does the method have the myinput argument in the first place...? You should work on your question more.